# wordpress display image caption if possible, but only on post page

Tags: image, wordpress, caption

I'm trying to make a function I can put into my functions.php that controls the images placed on each post's page. I want any image that has a caption to have that caption display under the image with paragraph tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function img_caption_only_in_posts( $current_html, $attr, $content ) {
global $post;
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id'    => '',
        'align' => 'alignnone',
        'width' => '',
        'caption' => ''
    ), $attr));
    if ( 1 > (int) $width || empty($caption) )
        return $content;

    if ($post->post_type=='page')
     $caption="";

    if ( $id ) $id = 'id="' . esc_attr($id) . '" ';

    return '<div ' . $id . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr($align) . '" style="width: ' . (10 + (int) $width) . 'px">'
. do_shortcode( $content ) . '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . $caption . '</p></div>';
}
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'img_caption_only_in_posts',10,3 );
```

I borrowed the code from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/4287/28218) and added the code for checking if the post is page or not.